# Snagit Chrome Extension Technology

Tags: javascript, c#, browser, screenshot

I need to create a cross-browser extension that can detect locally active windows. Recently I came through Snagit Chrome extension where clicking on "Screen" detects the active windows of the system and allows to capture any desired screen.

Can anyone please explain the platform/tech used to detect or get the window handles from browser app?
or any other way to get the handles..

Thanks

Comment: It's probably just the extension communicating with the installed Snagit software. I don't believe you can actually access that information directly from within the browser/extension.

Comment: Up until 2014 you could include .dll (windows), .so (Linux) and whatever they're called (Mac OS X) libraries in your Chrome extensions as NPAPI plugins. These could do pretty much everything on client's computer. But now those are phased out. http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

Comment: I do not have SnagIt installed on my system and yet it is able to detect local windows. So probably there must be some other logic being used for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get the technology used in SnagIt extension. 
SnagIt has used "WebRTC desktopCapture" for the same.
A sample can be found  [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:desktopcapture) .
WebRTC supports Chrome and Firefox for now. The desktopCapture feature enables user to share screen and this frame can be captured for screenshot as well.
Frame capture example can be seen [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webrtc)